# How to add contents to the pallet in netbeans?

Tags: html, mysql, user-interface, netbeans, web-applications

I'm following this tutorial from netbeans
[Creating a Simple Web Application Using a MySQL Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html#addJSTL)

I got to the point "Implementing JSTL code" and got stuck because the tutorial requires me to press the "DB Report" Button in the pallete. I have the Palette open but it only shows the HTML and Forms HTML tabs. I tried adding a new Category but it leaves a file with nothing in it.

I also saw if you go to tools>pallete you can see the HTML/JSP fragments and even see the database in the contents. I want to know how to transfer that to the pallete that actually shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything you have to do to transfer between the Pallete Manager window shown with Tools -> Palette -> HTML JSP Code Clips and the pallete shown on the right of the editor with Window -> IDE Tools -> Pallete.

These were the possible reasons (with corresponding fix)  I could see for not being able to see some of the palette categories such as Database.

- The Checkbox next to the category in the Palette Manager is not checked. (Check the checkbox or click Reset Palette)
- The category is visible but not expanded. (Just click the category name in the palette.)
- The category has scrolled below where you can see. (use the scrollbar on the side to scrolldown to see.)
- There is something wrong with your Netbeans installation, your missing a plugin needed to work with a category. ( Download Netbeans selecting the "All" package on the Downloads page and reinstall )

Right-clicking the Palette gives you mene options for "Refresh Palette" and "Reset Palette", that you might try even though I don't think it should be necessary.